# MapView in AlertDialog.Builder showing too dark

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-alertdialog, android-mapview

I've done creating MapView in AlertDialogBuilder,.

but when the map show is too dark and it's hard to see,.
anyone can help me solve this problem ?

I just want the map is normal like when we show the map at activity or fragment

here's my activity code :

```
private void showCustomAlert(String param){
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.customDialog));
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    switch (param){
        ... //other case code whith break point
        case "String Param" :
            final View rootMV = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_alert_maps, null);
            alertDialog.setView(rootMV);
            MapView mV = rootMV.findViewById(R.id.my_mv_id);
            mV.onCreate(alertDialog.onSaveInstanceState());
            mV.onResume();
            mV.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                    LatLng myll = new LatLng(-0.998812,109.784933);
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(myll)
                            .zoom(18)
                            .build();
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myll).title("Place Name"));
                    try {
                        MapsInitializer.initialize(getBaseContext());
                        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
            break;
    }
}
```

here's my custom layout code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title_view_maps"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Location"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/my_mv_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title_view_maps"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        style="@style/customDialog"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here's my custom style :

```
<style name="customDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and here's the result :
[MapView too dark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwISH.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should assign the customDialog style to the RelativeLayout, not the MapView.

Comment: my thanks @Ridcully, I'ts work

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

my thanks to @Ridcully for the answer

and it was just set the custom style to relativeLayout

from this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title_view_maps"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Location"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/my_mv_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title_view_maps"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        style="@style/customDialog"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

to be like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/customDialog">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title_view_maps"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Location"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/my_mv_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title_view_maps"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```